# Block of code executes twice in create-react-app development server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, indexeddb

```
const DBOpenReq = window.indexedDB.open("todo-todo", 2);

DBOpenReq.onsuccess = (event) => {
    db = event.target.result;
    console.log("IndexedDB connection success", db);
    listProjects();
    addProjectsInitally();
  };
```

Why does this(onsucess) block run twice in development server. I have used create-react-app.  I have deployed it on vercel. In vercel, `onsucucess` block, it only runs once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Disabling React Strict Mode***

---

Because you’ve created your React app using create-react-app, you’re likely to have this in your `index.js` file, or something similar.

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Simply remove the `<React.StrictMode>` tags around the  tag, and this should disable strict mode for your app! You can also only include this tag in pages where you do want strict mode enabled, to opt-in on a page-by-page basis.

Comment: How does ```<React.StrictMode>``` tags cause re-render of the component ?

Comment: React StrictMode is a component that checks for potential problems in an application during the development build, not in production. One of its features is that it intentionally double invokes certain lifecycle methods and functions to help identify unexpected side effects. This double invocation only occurs in development mode.